# Efeitos gráficos na Validação Javascript

Tags: javascript, validação

Qual este efeito/bibliotecaJS de validação onde a validação é realizada a cada preenchimento de campo e retornado as inconsistencias imediatamente e exibe informações flutuantes como este usado pelo cadastro do google.

Exemplos
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para as validações destacadas na caixa verde eu sugiro que você use o JQuery validation (olhe os demos em http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/) ou bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/

Para o tooltip da marcação em vermelho sugiro dois componentes, escolha o que achar melhor:

- Bootstrap (esse é o melhor): http://getbootstrap.com/. Dê uma olhada em todos os componentes e verá que tem muita coisa boa que você poderá utilizar na sua app. mas veja esses para fazer o efeito da caixa em vermelho http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation, http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers, http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic e http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips
- JQuery UI http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/ , não é exatamente igual mas funciona e vem com vários componentes que você poderá utilizar sem ter que ficar colocando um monte de bibliotecas separadas na sua aplicação.

Obs.: O bootstrap é muito bom mas os arquivos css dele podem mudar o visual do seu site se ele já estiver pronto. Use apenas em novas aplicações.

Comment: Olá @Marco Antonio Quintal, Obrigado era o que procurava.